# Expected Array but received array in Jest

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jestjs

I created unit (async) test in Jest. But when I get response from server:

```
[
    {
        name: "My name"
    },
    {
        name: "Another name"
    }
]
```

and test it:

```
test('Response from server', () => {
    get('my-url').end(error, response) => {
        expect(response.body).toBe(expect.any(Array))
    }
})
```

some error occurs:

```
Comparing two different types of values. Expected Array but received array.
```

It's working when I use `expect(response.body).any(Array)`. But is there any fix for `expect.toBe()`?

Comment: `expect(response.body).any(Array)` shouldn't work. `.any` doesn't exist on the response from `expect()` but on `expect` itself. The referenced code gives this error: "_TypeError: expect(...).any is not a function_".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use `toEqual` (not `toBe`) to compare objects and arrays. Use `toBe` for scalar data types only. If you like to check the response data type use `typeof` operator

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer above is really helpful, this how I implement it in my test

```
describe("GET /api/books", () => {
  it("should get all books", () => {
    return request(app)
      .get("/api/books")
      .expect(200)
      .expect("Content-Type", /json/)
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(expect.any(Array));
      });
  });
});
```